# Please explain this function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The code below is used to sort the int array in ascending or descending order

```
//codes borrowed from learncpp.com
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
void SelectionSort(int *anArray, int nSize, bool(*pComparison)(int, int)) {
    for(int iii=0; iii<nSize; iii++) {
        int nCurrent = iii;
        for(int jjj=iii+1; jjj<nSize; jjj++) {
            if(pComparison(anArray[nCurrent], anArray[jjj]))
                nCurrent = jjj;
            }
        swap(anArray[nCurrent], anArray[iii]);
    }
}
bool Ascending(int nX, int nY) {
    return nY>nX;
}
bool Descending(int nX, int nY) {
    return nY<nX;
}
bool EvensFirst(int nX, int nY) {
    if((nX%2)&&!(nY%2))
        return false;
    if(!(nX%2)&&(nY%2))
        return true;
    return Ascending(nX, nY);
}
void PrintArray(int *pArray, int nSize) {
    for(int kkk=0; kkk<nSize; kkk++)
        cout << pArray[kkk] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    int anArray[9] = {3, 5, 1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 2, 7};
    SelectionSort(anArray, 9, EvensFirst);
    PrintArray(anArray, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

Printing Result is 9 7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2 instead of 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9

Can anyone here please explain how does the bool function EvensFirst work?

Comment: Are you familiar with what `nX % 2` does? Or more specifically, if its value is zero or not zero, what it means in each case?

Comment: Not really, I feel confused with    ((nX%2)&&!(nY%2))

Comment: `%` is modulo. `% 2` is module 2 (the remainder you'd get if you divided the number by 2). If `nX % 2` is zero, then `nX` is even. If `nX % 2` is non-zero (1), then `nX` is odd. So `(nX %2) && ! (nY % 2)` is true if `nX` is odd and `nY` is even since zero has a false value, and 1 has a true value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from The Standard:

> Tthe binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a.
>   If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined (74)
>
> (74) According to work underway toward the revision of ISO C, the preferred algorithm for integer division follows the rules defined in the ISO Fortran standard, ISO/IEC 1539:1991, in which the quotient is always rounded toward zero.

Example:

`11 % 3 = 2`, because `11 = 3*3 + 2`

Now, operation modulo-2 can give us only two possible results: 0 or 1. Also:

**1)** For any given even number `N`, `N % 2` will always give 0. That's because even numbers are by definition multiplications of 2.

**2)** For any given odd number `M`, `M % 2` will always give 1. That's because any even number can be defined as `2K + 1`, where `K` is an `N0` (natural number or zero).

Because of the above, we can use `x % 2` expression as logical condition, because in C/C++ "0 is false, everything other is true".

So:

```
if(x%2)
{
  //x%2 != 0, which means x%2 = 1, which means x is an odd number
}
else
{
  //x%2 == 0, which means x is an even number
}
```

Now, let's go back to your `EvensFirst` function:

```
bool EvensFirst(int nX, int nY)
{
    if((nX%2)&&!(nY%2))
        return false;
    if(!(nX%2)&&(nY%2))
        return true;
    return Ascending(nX, nY);
}
```

This function accepts two arguments: `nX` and `nY` and it returns true if `nX` should be placed before `nY` (false otherwise). First, it checks the condition `(nX%2)&&!(nY%2)`. This condition essentially means:

**"Check, if `nX` is an odd number and `nY` is an even number."**

If it evaluates to true, function returns false - evens are taken first, so `nY` should be placed before `nX`).

Then, it checks for the second condition: `!(nX%2)&&(nY%2)`, which means:

**"Check, if `nX` is an even number and `nY` is an odd number."**

If it evaluates to true, function returns true - evens are taken first, so `nX` should be placed before `nY`.

If both these conditions evaluated to false, it means that either both of them are odd or both are evens. In this case, functions compares them using "Ascending" comparison - lower number will be taken first.

Answer (score 3):

The main thing in this program is the use of funtion pointer. `bool(*pComparison)(int, int)` is a  pointer to a function which returns `bool` type values and takes as parameter 2 `int` values. You can check the different outputs `SelectionSort(anArray, 9, Ascending);`or `SelectionSort(anArray, 9, Descending);` (if you have coded the selection sort function correctly).

Note: Based on different function pointer this general sorting routine will give different outputs. And the rest of the routine is basic sorting routine swapping the values of `min` or `max` to current element.

```
bool EvensFirst(int nX, int nY) {
    if((nX%2)&&!(nY%2)) //if nX is odd and nY is even the 
//nY should be in first position. So to change the order return false
        return false;
    if(!(nX%2)&&(nY%2))//if nX is even and nY is odd the 
//nX should be in first position. So to retain the order return true
        return true;
    return Ascending(nX, nY);// both even or both odd return the ascending function's output.
}
```

> If nx is even the if we divide it by 2 it will give remainder of 0.
>   For example, 12
>   12%2=0
>
> 34%2=0
>
> 9%2=1 ----> that's why this is odd.
>
> Every odd number can be written in the form `2m+1` Now if we divide this number by 2 we will get remainder of 1 as 1st part is giving remainder 0.
>
> Even number the explanation is same even number is represented by `2m`.So when divided by 2 it will give remainder 0.

```
if((nX%2)&&!(nY%2))  
       return false;
if nX is even it nX%2=0 and if nY is odd then ny%2=1
So expressin becomes
if(0 && 1)-->which evaluates to false and go to next condition.
```

Few wxamples to clarify your idea--

**Check if x is even**

```
if(x%2==0) 
  //x is even.

Also can be written as
if(!x%2)
  //x is even.
```

**Check if x is odd**

```
 if(x%2==1)
      // x is odd
    Also can be written as

    if(x%2)
      // x is odd.
```

**Check if x and y are both even**

```
   if(!x%2 && !y%2)
    //both even
```

**check if either of one is even**

```
 if(!x%2 || !y%2)
    //either of them is even
```

Comment: @JuenKhaw.: Look any even number when divided by 2 gives a remainder of 0 and any odd number gives 1. Isn't it?? nX%2 is equivalent of `nx is odd`. as if odd it will give 1 and enter in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The **operator modulo `%`** returns the remainder of the division of its operands. It can be used to check if a number is even or odd, because if the remainder of `x/2` is `0` it means that x is even. 
That means that if `x%2=0` than x is even, else it is odd.

---

Here's **how EvensFirst works**:

```
bool EvensFirst(int nX, int nY) {
    if((nX%2)&&!(nY%2)) //if nX is even and nY is odd
        return false;   //returns false
    if(!(nX%2)&&(nY%2)) //if nX is odd and nY is even
        return true;    //returns true
    //if they are both odd or even returns the result of ascending
    return Ascending(nX, nY); //true if nY > nX 
}
```

---

Here's **how you use EvensFirst**:

```
void SelectionSort(int *anArray, int nSize, bool(*pComparison)(int, int) {
    for(int iii=0; iii<nSize; iii++) {   //for each number in the array
        int nCurrent = iii;
        for(int jjj=iii+1; jjj<nSize; jjj++) {  //for each following elemnt
            if(pComparison(anArray[nCurrent], anArray[jjj])) //compare the two elements
                nCurrent = jjj; 
            }
        swap(anArray[nCurrent], anArray[jjj]); //and switch their positions if they are in the wrong order
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited again. Tell me if you need something else :)